# Una única página para diferentes slugs en Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, wordpress

Tengo una aplicación creada con Laravel la cual gestiona vehículos, estos vehículos son devueltos por a traves de un método por petición ajax. Bien esta ahí todo correcto, eso funciona sin problemas, el problema viene a que esos datos tienen que ser leidos por diferentes wordpress.

He conseguido recoger todos los datos de los vehículos con fetch en una página creada de wordpress pero necesito poder ver los datos de cada vehículo y para eso necesito crear una única página en wordpress que sea la plantilla con los datos del vehículo pero no consigo encontrar la solucion, llevo ya mas de dos días en ello y no encuentro nada.

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Deberías de subir el código que hayas intentado para poder ayudarte

Comment: Ciertamente el código que tengo esta relacionado con laravel y funciona perfectamente, el problema que tengo es que no se por donde empezar ni que hacer para poder crear los slugs de las páginas en wordpress de forma dinámica. @Youshiro

Answer (score -1):

Hola podrías investigar con custom post type y creando categorías, también haciendo uso de la category.php donde podemos listar items por categoría he internamente crear un slug que muestre cada auto por ej single-auto.php y el custom post type tendría que llamarse auto. Así podrías tener la single-auto.php para mostrar cada auto a modo plantilla, saludos.